# How to link Cryptodome with pycryptodome?

Tags: python-3.x, pycryptodome

Im using windows 11, with python 3.10 installed

I have made sure to install pycryptodomex throught command:

```
pip3 install pycryptodomex
```

but I still have this error

```
  File "C:\Users\theac\mtkclient\mtkclient\Library\hwcrypto_dxcc.py", line 10, in <module>
    from Cryptodome.Util.number import bytes_to_long
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cryptodome'
```

how to fix this ?

I have try install pycryptodome for python 1 , and all sort of commands. but still the error keep pessistent

```
D:\begonia\begonia_eea_global_images_V11.0.3.0.PGGEUXM_20191210.0000.00_9.0_eea\images>pip3 install pyCryptodome
Requirement already satisfied: pyCryptodome in d:\users\theac\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (3.17)

D:\begonia\begonia_eea_global_images_V11.0.3.0.PGGEUXM_20191210.0000.00_9.0_eea\images>pip3 install pyCryptodomex
Requirement already satisfied: pyCryptodomex in d:\users\theac\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (3.17)
```

Comment: Is there a need to have both `pyCryptodome` and `pyCryptodomex`? What if you uninstall `pyCryptodome`? `pip3 uninstall pyCryptodome`